# Why can't members of my organisation see my boards?

Tags: trello

The boards are all visible, etc by organisation, not members, but they can't see them at all let alone interact with them. I have also tried inviting members to the boards individually (which incidentally is ridiculously hard to do), but with no success.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to either make the board visible to the organization (from the board preferences) or add them to the board.

If you've set the board to organization visible, members should be able to view the board, but they can only interact with it (move, edit, add cards, etc.) if they've been invited to and accepted the invitation to the board.

Comment: Adding organization members to the board should most definitely be easier. We've got a card for it here: https://trello.com/card/board/make-it-easier-to-add-organization-members-to-a-board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e863e8b7c30b184f69bf9a3

Comment: I'm not sure how this works but the above answer, while helpful, is misleading, as making the board visible to an organisation (which I have done) doesn't actually work as advertised. My colleague Rob has posted on the card board adding to the requests for this to be much simpler. Thank you.

Comment: Yay, comments. That's what I meant to do!

Comment: If you've set it to organization visible and org members still can't see the org on from the organization profile, then you might have a bug. Send an email to support@trello.com. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here. Making a board Org Visible does not allow others in the Org to see it. Email to support sent.